# How Do I Use A Local Variable Outside A Foreach Loop (C#)

Tags: c#, loops, foreach

I have an array list where I am adding numbers but need to use those numbers somewhere else in my code outside of the foreach loop. How do I use CampaignLink outside of the foreach loop? Also, if I want to assign the (1) or (2) or (3) I added in CampaignLink to something else later, How do I do that?

My code

```
List<int> userDetails = new List<int>();
userDetails.Add(1);
userDetails.Add(2);
userDetails.Add(3);
  
foreach(var CampaignLink in userDetails)
{
    Console.WriteLine(CampaignLink);
}
```

Comment: Technically, it's not an array but a list of integers. Terminology matters, sorry. However, you can access single items using square brackets `userDetails[0]` or System.Linq `userDetails.ElementAt(0)`. Hope I could help.

Answer (score 1):

CampaignLink is declared in the foreach statement and therefore only exists in that. However userDetails exists outside of it and you can refer to its contents elsewhere.

To assign the contents of userDetails to something else later you could do the following, for example:

```
var somethingElse = userDetails[1];
```

I think it is pertinent to bring up the difference between value types (such as int) and reference types (anything defined in a class) and the difference in what happens when you assign them. When you assign a value type it is independent to its source. They just have the same value. However when you assign a reference type, it will be the same thing, and so changing it in one place will cause it to be changed in the other too.